# Nested actions in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, filtering, action

I have two actions, which they filter my default data. These actions are:

```
export function filterBySide(data, product_side) {
    const filtered_side_data = data.filter(record =>{
        return record.side.match(product_side)
    });

    return {
        type: FILTER_BY_SIDE,
        payload: {
            filtered_side_data
        }
    };
}
export function filterByStatus(data, product_status) {
    const filtered_status_data = data.filter(record =>{
            return record.status.match(product_status)
    });

    return {
        type: FILTER_BY_STATUS,
        payload: {
            filtered_status_data
        }
    };
}
```

I attached them in two drop down lists and they filtered my data in a grid. My problem is that i want them to execute synchronously. To be more precise when i choose a product's side and then i choose a products status i want to filter my already filtered data by status

Answer (score 2):

You could do the filtering inside your list component. Just record in the store what filters are selected and in the component use it to filter all the data.

I highly recommend you to see redux creator [Dan Abramov's tutorial on redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux). At the end you'll be able to properly do an app that filters data.

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand, should i dispatch the two actions inside of list components??

Comment: I m new to react redux that why i find it difficult to cope with these kind of problems

Comment: These actions are working,  BUT i want them to work synchronously

Comment: When you want each action to be dispatched?

Comment: I have two dropDown lists, the first one must filtered tha data by the side value, so i dispatch the first action inside this component(Dropdown). The other action is dispatched inside the other dropDown. The problem is that when i use the dropdowns i dont want the current state to change. I want to filter the already filtered data. Should i make the actions different using some if's??

Comment: You have to do filtering on the component that is rendering data. Spend some time to learn and watch the tutorial. I think is the fastest way for you ;)